# Why does a minipage in Beamer affect list spacing, and how do I fix it?

Tags: beamer, minipage, line-spacing

I'm experimenting with a parallel form of nested `itemize` items in Beamer, using `minipage`s to separate parent and child list items.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Sequential item 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Minor item 1a
    \item Minor item 2a
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \item Parallel item 2
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.75\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Minor item 1b
      \item Minor item 2b
      \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: beamer output]

Why does the sublist in the parallel case have different vertical spacing, and how do I get it to have the same spacing as the sequential case?

(Please note that I have already spotted the horrid vertical misalignment of the two sides -- that's a separate question.)

Comment: The fact that `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth} \item Parallel item 2` doesn't give an error is a feature that it is best not to use. `\item` should only be used in lists, it is just the error detection failed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is trying to set top level lists with `\itemsep` of

```
> 3.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt.
```

and second level lists with a tighter setting of

```
> 0.0pt plus 1.0pt.
```

But you have put the top level item inside a group (inside several layers of groups and boxes actually) so the nesting structure is corrupted and you get the top level spacing.

You could reset `\itemsep` but not putting groups around the outer items would be better.

Comment: Obviously I don't doubt your answer for an instant (:-), but I really can't see how, if the nesting structure is regular, the nested groups don't "unwind" in what I would call a "proper" way ??

Comment: @Brent.Longborough because the top level `\item` sets up the context so that second level lists know they are second level but you then do `\end{minipage}` and all that context is dicarded. _then_ you do your second level list, bit it's not really anywhere now, it is nested in the outer itemize but not in the scope of an `\item`.

Comment: OK, but surely the matching `\begin{minipage}` should have pushed that context onto the "group stack"? "... all that context is discarded ..." sounds a bit draconian. Or is my internal model broken?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough the boxes are not relevant, you have  `\begin{itemize} {\item} \begin{itemize} \item zzz`  but the inner list is in an inconsistent state as it is in the scope of the outer  `itemize` but not in the scope of the `\item` as you have hidden that in a group.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough the `\begin{minipage}` pushes _a_ context on to the stack but that is the context before `\item` sets up the fact that you are in an outer item, that's the problem, you don't want to return to that context.

Comment: Ah, I see; so inside a group, you don't inherit what was in force outside? (I appreciate your patience -- I guess the TeX programming model doesn't match my weird ideas drawn from other languages and SICOP)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough no inside the group you inherit what is outside, the problem is that all the relevant settings by `\item` are not seen _outside_  the group as you have gone `{\item}` so after the `}` (or `\end{minipage}` in your case) the settings by `\item` are lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32314/discussion-between-brent-longborough-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: @Brent.Longborough no in this case you can't attribute it to tex weirdness:-) The same would be true in any kind of language that has any notion of local scope:-)